# irreducible one-dimensional representations of $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ over the field of real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I`m wondering if there is any irreducible one-dimensional representation of the group $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ over the field of real numbers.

I found that there are $n$ irreducible one-dimensional representations of $\mathbb Z_n$ over the field of complex numbers. (which are given by $e^{2i\pi j/n},$ when $0<j<n-1$). I know also that one-dimensional representation over field $\mathbb C$ is a two-dimensional representation over field $\mathbb R$. so, this means that there is no irreducible one-dimensional representations of $\mathbb Z_n$ over field $\mathbb R$?

I`ll be thankful for having answers.

Comment: You have been around for five months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: The only roots of unity in $\mathbb R$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: If $n$ is even, there is the parity homomorphism $k\mapsto(-1)^k,$ and, of course there is always the constant $k\mapsto 1$ for any $n.$

Comment: Also, you only gave $n-2$ complex representations. Presumably you meant $0\leq j\leq n-1$ rather than $0<j<n-1?$

Comment: A representation $\phi$ of $\mathbb Z_n$ is entirely determined by $\phi(1).$ If $A=\phi(1),$then you need $A^n=1,$ so the order of $A$ must be a multiple of $n.$ The only real numbers of finite order are $\pm 1.$ But when $n$ is odd, $(-1)^n=-1\neq 1.$